# TFLite: Is it possible to convert a H5 model but with a different input shape using Keras' load_model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tensorflow-lite

I currently use this script to convert my H5 model to TFLite:

```
 # CONVERTING TO TFLITE FORMAT
    g.save(os.path.join(save_dir, 'full_generator_{}_{}.h5'.format(epoch_number, current_loss)), include_optimizer=False)

    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(
        os.path.join(save_dir, 'full_generator_{}_{}.h5'.format(epoch_number, current_loss)), custom_objects={'ReflectionPadding2D': ReflectionPadding2D})
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
    tflite_model = converter.convert()

    open(os.path.join(save_dir, 'full_generator_{}_{}.tflite'.format(epoch_number, current_loss)),
         "wb").write(tflite_model)
 # /CONVERTING TO TFLITE FORMAT
```

My problem is that the H5 model has input shape's dimensions of 256x256x3. What I would want is that the converted TFLite model has input shape's dimensions of 800x800x3.

I know it's possible with the frozen graph TF function.

But is it possible with `load_model`?

Comment: You can't change the input shape of a frozen graph and hence of the TFLite file.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your model in a tf.function with a new input signature and convert `from_concrete_functions` instead.

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(
    os.path.join(save_dir, 
                 'full_generator_{}_{}.h5'.format(epoch_number, current_loss)), 
    custom_objects={'ReflectionPadding2D': ReflectionPadding2D})

wrapped_model = tf.function(lambda input_data: model(input_data))
input_spec = tf.TensorSpec((800, 800, 3), model.inputs[0].dtype)
concrete_func = wrapped_model.get_concrete_function(input_spec)
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_func])
```

You can also make a tf.function that resizes the input to match your models required shape if your model doesn't support changed size.